# Does Array<never> sometimes have a non-zero length in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code example.

```js
const nevers: Array<never> = []
const empty: [] = nevers;  // ERROR
```

In the example `empty` is defined as a zero tuple (or empty array) that can never contain any values. On the other hand `nevers` is defined as an array of values that can never exists. One would think that such Array would always have zero length as well. However, the assignment in the example gives an error which states that `nevers` could have a non-zero length. Does this mean that a const of type `Array<never>` could actually sometimes contain some values? Obviously you could always break the type correspondence through runtime mutations but that is not what I'm asking.

Comment: With a not null assertion this can happen: `const nevers: Array<never> = [null!, null!]`. Generally there is nothing in `Array<never>` that ensures length `0`

Comment: also, using explicit length: `const nevers: Array<never> = new Array<never>(2)`

Comment: And what would be a purpose of `const nevers: Array<never>`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. for example an array of errors returned by something that never fails